# IPv6 simple home LAN server confiiguration

Tags: ipv6, file-server

How do we configure a IPv6 host for access through its global IPv6 address?  If that's what we do.This is a server running services for a small home LAN that I want to access when I'm away.

I have been using the server host's IPv6 global address, but the dynamically assigned address has a limited lifetime. (It expired on me.)

From my google research I gather than what I'm doing is not something people often do -- so perhaps it's just completely wrong headed? I find info on configuration for enterprise environments but not much for little guys like me.  Running a DNS to track moving IP addresses is probably not an appropriate solution for a small personal site that does not have a public presence.

I can manually set the `preferred_lft` to `forever` but this is quickly overwritten by the system that's working with the router to assign valid addresses. This suggests that I'm barking up the wrong tree.

So what *is*  the best solution here? Some simple documentation would be great.

Comment: Add an additional, static address that has the same prefix as the expiring addresses, and a fixed host part. For example, if your prefix is `2001:db8:101:3a22/64`, add the address `2001:db8:101:3a22::10` to the interface. If the prefix also changes with time, this method won't work.

Comment: It all depends on how your ISP does things. If your ISP does things like my ISP, it'll announce an IPv6 prefix to the hardware directly connected to it (for me, my home router), which in turn will announce that prefix to all machines in my local network. If you want DNS resolution for your server, you need a dynamic DNS provider. So: Edit your question and describe your setup (ISP or home router? Which brand and model? Can it pass on IPv6 prefixes?) etc.

Comment: @JohanMyréen So: `ip add 2001:db8:101:3a22::10/64 dev enp0s28 scope global preferred_lft forever`. That is working. Let's see how long it lasts.

Comment: @dirkt Don't want externally addressable DNS. I have one for the LAN but don't need to expose it. ISP prefix is put by the router. I'm trying out dirkt suggestion which seems simple and reasonable. Watching that.

Comment: @StephenBoston Yes, but to make it persistent across reboots you will have to use some configuration mechanism defined by your distribution.

Answer (score 0):

After suggestions by JohanMyreen I have the following netplan configuration where I take the address from the one assigned via DHCP and change the last field to the same value as the last field of the static IPv4 address which is assigned by DHCP reservation - that simply for ease of documentation, not for any functional reason.

```
 network:
   version: 2
   renderer: networkd
   ethernets:
     enp0s8:
       dhcp4: yes
       dhcp6: no
       addresses:
         - 2001:123:456:789:abc:def:123:120/64
       nameservers:
         addresses: [1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1,"2606:4700:4700::1111","2606:4700:4700::1001"]
```

**Johan** and **dirkt** warn that the reliability of this approach depends on the router maintaining a static prefix. I take some reassurance in noting that the address has changed while the prefix has not changed. I asked my ISP tech support for info and the person I talked with didn't know so I'll have to try again with an email.

Comment: Note that basically all ISPs I know like to make no guarantee about your IP address unless you have a contract for a static IP address. So while your IPv6 prefix may not have changed in the past, in theory it probably could change anytime. Of course, if in reality that happens very infrequently, you don't need dynamic DNS.

Comment: @dirkt Good point.  I've had the same IPv4 address for years, has been persistent over two moves and a 'plan' upgrade. The one time it did change was when the modem was down for two weeks. Likely they recycle an  IP address only when it is inactive?

Comment: It totally depends on the ISP. I had an ISP with a daily forced reconnect, sometimes the IPv4 address stayed the same, sometimes I got a new one. YMMV.